# Form getting result from message box with multiple variables OK and Cancel

Tags: powershell, dialog

I am trying to get an OK or Cancel result from a script I'm writing, I have multiple variables involved that drill down into one message. Attached is my script, basically what I need for it to do is when "OK" is pressed continue on with the AD account creation, when "Cancel" is pressed either close the form or go back to it I haven't decided yet, I think I am on the right track by assigning it as a variable but currently the account is created when both OK or cancel are selected. BTW my code is in the attached picture.

[image: Script]

Comment: Posting a screenshot of incomplete code is not going to cut it. Please make your code sample [minmal, complete and verifyable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it in text form, so we can copy/paste it. Also describe what is not working with the current code. Don't make things difficult for the people you're asking for help.

Comment: I'd also suggest scrubbing the screenshot and/or code when you repost. You're revealing at least one phone number and the business name (along with some internal OU structure information). Obviously this is a security problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go look up the `Switch` command. Here's how I would use it in your situation:

```
Switch($true){
    {$RadioButton1.Checked} { $Room = 'Yellowstone Room #6042' }
    {$RadioButton1.Checked} { $Room = 'Shenandoah Room #6043' }
    {$RadioButton1.Checked} { $Room = 'Everglades Room #6042' }
    {$RadioButton1.Checked} { $Room = 'Gettysburg Room #6038' }
    {$RadioButton1.Checked} { $Room = 'Antietam Room #6030' }
    {$RadioButton1.Checked} { $Room = 'Yosemite Room #6039' }
    {$RadioButton1.Checked} { $Room = 'Zion Room #6040' }
    default { $Room = $Null }
}

$MsgBox = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Thank you $a, you have selected $Room and breakout $h, please contact Patrick Sullivan (703-434-4621) for technical assistance or the NSS servicedesk (1-800-871-9983)","Thank you for registering!",1)
If($MsgBox -eq 'OK'){
    New-ADUser -Name $d -AccountExpirationDate $j -AccountPassword $k -Description $i -DisplayName $d.prop -Enabled $true -GivenName $a -MobilePhone $e -SamAccountName $c -Surname $b -Path "OU=VPC VDI,OU=VPC,OU=Hosted Accounts,DC=net,DC=its,DC=l-3com,DC=com"
}
Else{
    Write-Host "You pressed cancel"
}
```

That should do what you were attempting. Or, without changing your code much...

Change the `"OK"` section to `If($1 -eq "OK"){New-ADUser .....}Else{Write-Host "You pressed cancel!"}`